# Please raise the threshold for auto awarding bounties

Tags: discussion, feature-request, bounty

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29692510/use-index-and-match-on-another-fulltext-index-gives-error-cant-find-fulltext-i) **(NOT MINE)** was (and still is) unanswered, so I placed a bounty on it.

When the bounty was very near to its expiration, somebody published a random garbage answer which not only does not answer, but doesn't even remotely address the question.

It's pretty clear that he did that in order to get 25 reputation points for nothing. That's what I call a "bounty troll".

I don't care about the reputation that I wasted, nor do I care about him getting reputation for a garbage answer. It does bother me that the bounty mechanism, which is supposed to be a tool for improving the quality of SO as a source of information, is so easily perverted to obtain the exact opposite effect: what previously was a valuable, unfortunately unanswered question which deserved more attention, now is an unanswered question with a garbage answer which, by the way, is wrongly implicitly signaled as the accepted answer. This is worse than no answer, because

- people will waste time reading the non-answer
- the question will receive even less attention because it appears to have already an accepted answer
- (not sure about this one) it may even get boosts in search results leading to more people looking for an answer ending up wasting their time reading garbage.

To me it's obvious what SO should do to prevent these situations which degrade the quality of SO:

1) **Raise the threshold**

> If you do not award [...] the highest voted answer [...] **with a minimum score of 2** will be awarded half the bounty amount.

The current score threshold of 2 is ridiculously low. My question is the proof that even a garbage answer that cites some random piece of documentation remotely related to the subject of the answer can achieve a score of 2.

2) **Don't mark the awarded answer as accepted**

Leave the empty checksign that non-accepted answers usually have. An answer that has been automatically awarded a bounty is not an accepted answer

Unless you may want to just remove the auto-awarding mechanism altogether, which is very questionable in the first place.

Comment: I don't get your second point. An automatic bounty award *doesn't* mark an answer as accepted. There's no checkmark on the answer you linked. It's just that only the person who asked the question sees the invisible checkmark because they're the only ones that can accept an answer. Displaying that for other users just to emphasize it's not accepted would be a bit confusing.

Comment: Don't get your point regarding _trolling_? That was a valid attempt to answer your poorly asked/to broad question. The only troll, is you as far I can see, stressing the site for your overly broad question.

Comment: This is something you'll have to deal with.  There is not much point in blaming a low-rep SO user and his friends, although you are certainly allowed to dislike it, core problem is that you asked a question that nobody knows the real answer to.  Don't ask unanswerable questions, MySQL makes a living providing support to their customers, they'll happily take your call.

Comment: The garbage answerer is also a serial plagiarist. Anyone want to do the honours and go through their profile? It's late where I am

Comment: Why is everybody here assuming i asked the question while you can clearly see i didn't?? I only placed the bounty.

Comment: @Hans Passant 1. "there is not much point in blaming the user" that's while i blame SO for placing a low threshold. 2. I didn't ask the question. 3. It's not broad at all, it is just difficult to answer, or maybe the answer is "there's no solution". 4. If nobpdy knows the answer or there's no solution, it doesn't mean the question is poor, and posting an answer that doesn't address the point is not a correct behavior

Comment: Setting the threshold higher just doesn't accomplish anything.  You still don't have an answer, still are out of the rep and only get such a user to invite more friends to vote on his post.  There will be more abuse and less people that answer bountied questions, nobody is ahead.

Comment: @πάντα you call me troll based on the assumption that I asked the question, if only you took the time to read the name below it you would know it wasn't the case, and also see Pekka's comment which confirms the answerer in fact is a troll.

Comment: @matteo Oops, sorry for that.

Comment: Would You get the rep cut off even if the award is not given? If raising the threshold is not a solution, then the solution is some moderator deleting the answer, as i flagged it for not being an answer

Answer (score 3):

Disclaimer: I have not used the bounty system personally.

---

#### Addressing this specific case

The question is not very clear.  I'm no expert on those tags, but I had a hard time figuring out what was actually asked.  Merely editing the question to make it more understandable, or at least make the core question more obvious might have gotten the post the extra attention it needed without a bounty.  Because of how the question was worded, many users probably found that answer useful enough and upvote worthy.  And the answer seems like an honest attempt to answer the question, whatever it is.

> It's pretty clear that he did that in order to get 25 reputation points for nothing.

No the user took the time to post an answer, and 3 other users thought that answer was helpful.  I am a bit surprised to see those upvotes on a post with lackluster formatting and a rather sparse explanation.  However, it is by no means "trolling" or a "random garbage answer."<sup>1</sup>

I think your case is a weird situation that just played out in way you didn't like.  The answer might have been bad, but I feel this was more a failure of SO's usually on-point moderation.  With just one more downvote, the answer would have a score of 1 and wouldn't qualify for the automatic bounty award.  Or as [Pekka investigated](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/305615/please-raise-the-threshold-for-auto-awarding-bounties/305617?noredirect=1#comment244644_305615), it was plagiarism and could have been custom flagged with the details.  At the very least, the deletion of the answer rectifies this situation.

<sup>1</sup> As of now the answer is deleted, and you're right (and I was wrong) that it is dishonest answer.  But you could have been a bit more eloquent in describing it than "garbage answer that cites some random piece of documentation."  You could have, for example, included the random documentation being "cited" (or in this case plagiarized).  Or even left that comment on the answer itself to help warn others.

#### Your request in general

> 2 is a ridiculously low score threshold

I disagree.  In low traffic tags, people are lucky to even get a single upvote.  I'm guess the threshold is intentionally low to allow traffic tags to actually benefit from the bounty system.

> Don't mark the awarded answer as accepted Leave the empty checksign that non-accepted answers usually have. An answer that has been automatically awarded a bounty is not an accepted answer

I have no idea what you are talking about.  This is the current behavior, and your question has no accepted answer.  This is what I currently see, and there is no check marking the answer as accepted.  There is only a notice that the answer previously got a bounty.

> [image: Answer awarded bounty but not accepted]

Comment: I didn't ask the question, i just placed the bounty. You say you're no expert on those tags and you had a hard time figuring out what the question means. I am probably a bit more expert on those tags and i can tell you the question is cristal clear; i had no trouble understanding it, as i have no trouble seeing that the answer doesn't answer it. It's not that i don't like it, it's that it doesn't address the question

Comment: "No the user took the time to post an answer" - no, he took the time to copy and paste some random slightly related piece of documentation, and yes, three people found that useful, which proves the threshold of so low

Comment: @matteo I updated the post to address these plagiarism concerns.  Plagiarism does count as a "garbage" answer, but it would have been a lot easier on everyone else involved if you just said it was plagiarism instead of laziness.

Comment: I didn't "just say it was plagiarism" because I didn't know it was and whether or not that in itself was an issue. If the user had copied and pasted a *relevant* piece of documentation that *did* address the answer, I would have considered it a good answer worth accepting and awarding. The issue isn't lazyness either. The issue with the answer was  it was garbage. The fact that only by realizing that it was plagium you all realized it was garbage, proves how little everybody here understands about the subject of the question, and yet everybody feels like criticizing the question.

Comment: And the fact that I got 7 downvotes right here all based on the assumption that I was the author of the question, while the name of the author is right below it, proves how easy it is to get a handful of random (up or down) votes on SO, hence making a threashold of 2 roughly equivalent to no threshold. @Hans Passant might have a point saying raising the question wouldn't solve the problem, but then, that questions the very idea of autoaward.

Comment: And let me stress once more that the claim that the question is unclear, too broad, or poorly phrased, is absolutely wrong. The question couldn't be clearer or more specific. The only issue with that question (which is by no means the asker's fault) is that it is a difficult question to answer, and it is indeed likely that it has no solution. An informed answer saying "you just can't accomplished that" (with some evidence) would be a perfect answer (if it is the case), and an answer like "I don't think you can accomplish that" (with partial evidence or reasoning) would be totally acceptable.

Comment: @matteo the downvotes for feature requests (which your question really is) can also indicate "I don't think this is a worthwhile feature."  So the votes really could be "I agree but I don't think changing the minimum threshold is a good idea."

Comment: (SO doesn't let me edit my own comment after X minutes, so don't blame me if I have to comment once more just to correct a typo of my own): I meant "raising the *threshold*", not "raising the question", of course

Comment: really? So let's suppose (not this case, of course), that someone propose a feature request for a feature that you deem very reasonable and you appreciate the proposal, but considering all the pros and cons you think in the end it should not be implemented. Are you really saying it would be good practice to downvote it?

Comment: @matteo yes.  That's correct.  See [What's meta](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta).  "_On posts tagged feature-request, voting indicates agreement or disagreement with the proposed change rather than just the quality or usefulness of the post itself._"  Of course, people can still vote according to the post's quality, but it can mean just disagreement.