# User doesn't give an answer but gets a bounty reward

Tags: discussion, reputation, bounty, not-an-answer

I had a technical task that I could not resolve, so I created a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33272788/setting-proxy-credentials-via-firefox-extension) to which no one gave me an answer due the technical complexity. To get more attention I started a bounty. This did not help much. But, two hours before bounty expired, some user came to my question! He did not answer it but just copy-pasted part of the documentation from the link I had already provided.

So, after another day of no answer, this user got half of the bounty (100 points). It's not fair.

Why give the points to the user? It's not an answer. It even started with the sentence:

> I am not able to provide the exact answer you looking for.

I have flagged that answer as *not an answer*, but nothing happened.

I believe this is a serious problem. Some users can collect a lot of points by not even providing answers.

Is there a way to solve this problem correctly?

Comment: check the bounty rules. if he got at least 2 upvotes, it's expected and how the system works. It's to compensate for users who never award their bounties I guess.

Comment: Down voted his answer... this is the [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33272788/setting-proxy-credentials-via-firefox-extension) you are talking about, right?

Comment: @penne12, yes, it is

Comment: wow... yeah it is a pretty bad answer, considering..... no clue how he got +4..

Comment: "Is there any way to solve this problem correctly? " - first you have to put the actual problem in perspective here. Its not that bounties get auto-awarded to bad answers; that is not a feature of the site. The problem here is that a really poor answer got upvotes, and as a result of that problem the bounty got partially awarded to it.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/305615/4320665

Comment: Putting it bluntly, if you want a better outcome then don't ask a question that nobody knows the answer to.  SO does not provide a warranty and is not a substitute for the kind of paid support you can get from a 1st party.

Comment: @HansPassant How is someone supposed to know if anybody can answer it if they don't ask the question in the first place?

Comment: Even if you have absolutely no idea that it is unanswerable then it is still very easy to find out.  First strong cue comes after one hour.  The guarantee is delivered after 9 days.

Comment: But why is the bounty given automatically, I don't think it should, upvotes don't necessarily mean a good answer, being this exhibit A

Comment: @pnuts, yes, someone from this thread give link to this discussion in comments to answer there.

Comment: I also thought this "2 up = half bounty" thing yould lead to undesired results. Of course, as stated in the answer by @rene : *"You got what you asked for/invested in"* (although I bet this meta post brought more attention than the bounty itself). But two upvotes are too easily earned in some cases. Maybe something like "each upvote brings 5% of the bounty, unless it is fully awarded (manually) by the asker" could be more appropriate?

Comment: @Marco13 that is one option, another option is that we don't up vote low quality answers on borderline questions.

Comment: @rene Who is "we"? I personally tend to only upvote when I can really judge whether the answer will be useful for the asker. And often, a question gets a bounty exactly *when* there are only few people who can give a correct/helpful answer *at all* (and thus, when only few people can *judge* whether an answer is helpful). I'm particularly hesitant to upvote bounty answers, even when I think that it is helpful, exactly for this 2-vote rule (unless *the asker itself* also accepts/upvotes). Also related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260141/how-to-willingly-not-award-a-bounty?

Comment: *We* as in the community at large. I would really hope everyone votes like you do @Marco13 but looking at questions and answers in some tags really makes you believe that a part of the community up vote for effort, not for quality/usefulness.

Comment: Would love to see a grace period and notification to bounty owner: "User X will be automatically awarded bounty in 24 hours. If this answer does not deserve the bounty being awarded, do YYY"

Comment: I;ve seen this in different places. There are several Boba Fetts (bounty hunters) around that post ridiculously incomplete answers to bounty questions, hoping that no one will actually asnwer them and get the reward for themselves. Ive seen this several times in the MATLAB tag, for example.

Comment: @AnderBiguri if you see the same people repeatedly do that then it would be worth to flag one of their 'answers' for mod attention I'd say, explaining that it is a repeated offense. You can't do much about the singular cases, but people who repeat their actions can be caught and tossed into the Sarlacc pit.

Comment: And how ethical it is @msangel, just because you didn't like someone's answer, you went on down voting all his posted questions???
You did not even bother to post the down vote comments!

Comment: @SyntaX, I haven't did anything similar, anyway, we are in the thread where is administration(I am sure they can see who has voted down), and I can guarantee that I haven't vote down any other your answer or any question anywhere.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I'm not so convinced that the answer here is the problem. <sup>1</sup>

Your question is explaining a certain problem in only textual form, with a single link to documentation. Personally I don't find it a very clear problem statement or what you actually want as an answer. If I run into that same problem in my own code implementation I would have to link your text to my code. In other words: For me your question could have used a code example.

The OP basically took your link, summarized/took the most relevant part of that rather extensive page and used that as the basis for the answer. Beyond that the OP provided documentation to two events that can be used to implement/mimic the behavior you're after. The OP provided additional links for browser specific implementation details of the used component. 
The OP could also have said: *No, that is not possible, there is no other approach.*

Given your conceptual way of asking a technical question the OP saw no problem in providing you with a conceptual/high-level approach. I don't see a bad intent by that OP. (*hello meta-effect*)

That your Not An Answer flag is declined is the correct response. The answer tries to address the question. That it isn't up to your standards is partly caused by your approach in asking the question.

The answer has value and with that it is eligible for up votes. The bounty that comes with it is a bonus.

Final note: A bounty is only meant to give your question attention, it is in no way a guarantee to get an (quality) answer. You got what you asked for/invested in.

<sub>1. Three users with >20K privilege decided differently, they deleted the [answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPsqd.png) and an SE employee investigated voting so the deletion is permanent</sub>

Comment: Personally I found such way or earning points fair, so nothing will stop my from behave same way. This questoin was only for clarifying public point of view on this situation. Thanks for the responce.

Comment: @msangel: If you see bad behavior that (for various unfortunate reasons of group dynamics) isn't adequately punished, the correct thing to do is *not* to drop your criticism of it and start emulating it.

Comment: @NathanTuggy I'm a little bit confused by your comment. I argued that the answer was not that bad, maybe not up vote worthy. If you're suggesting that the OP should not answer bountied questions, what should be done instead?

Comment: @rene: The OP appears (from their wording) to have taken the wrong thing from this experience and decided that no one could stop them from posting useless answers on bountied questions in an attempt to cash in on misplaced votes. Since that is what they were originally objecting to out of principle, abandoning that principle is what I was decrying.

Comment: @NathanTuggy OK, I didn't read it that way but is that is how it should be read, I agree.

Comment: "Three users with >20K privilege decided differently, they deleted the answer"  Why ?? If it is a bad answer it should be downvoted. But deletion does not make sense to me. Was this done, just to overcome the bounty problem?

Comment: @shock_gone_wild I dunno but feel free to ask a new question about that. I'm also curious to know the answer

Comment: @shock_gone_wild Answers would not usually be deleted just because they are low quality - that's what downvoting is for.  However if the answer isn't really addressing the question, doesn't even attempt to answer the question and simply quotes from the question itself, then it's not an answer and should be deleted as such.

Comment: @AleksG you can check the deleted answer, I would appreciate if youy can share your view on it.

Comment: I just asked a http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311395/deletion-of-unsatisfactory-answer-that-awarded-a-bounty seperate question for diskussion about this problem

Comment: @rene From my reading the question, the answer the page, linked to in the question, I tend to agree that the answer doesn't provide any additional useful information - certainly not anything useful to the OP of the question. I personally probably wouldn't vote to delete the answer, but I would most likely downvote.  Not deleting, simply because for some future users it could be useful to have the information from the linked reference page shown on this page itself, next to the question.  However I believe I do understand why it was deleted.

Comment: i have seen MUCH worse answers that were not deleted. I think, this came only through this meta question and the 'bounty problem'

Answer (score 0):

You are starting from the false premise that the user who posted the question and also added the bounty is playing fair and will award the bounty. Even with the upvote system in play there is no inceptive for the person posting a bounty on its own question to play fair.

"You cut, I choose" is a good rule and this is what the upvote is trying to achieve. The upvote system should even go to 100% if the user posting the question and offering the bounty is the same.